# Adding custom domain but getting operation pending error on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to add custom domain "www.abc.com" to app engine project named "abc-123".

The error thrown up is:

> There is an operation pending for this application. Please wait and try again.

Even tried deleting the project and adding again but no luck.

Has anyone else faced a similar problem?

[image: error on mapping www domain]

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, but no solution, yet.

Comment: I have the same error message, but it happens when deleting an existing subdomain. (I tried to delete it fairly quickly after it was created I think, and it appears that broke the process.)

Comment: Trying to delete using command line `gcloud app domain-mappings delete` showed more info. In my case it was an issue deleting the managed certificate: (gcloud.app.domain-mappings.delete) Error Response: [13] Error deleting the managed certificate for this domain mapping.

Comment: An hour or so later I was automatically able to delete the domain mapping without error from the web UI.